# how to eliminate the rows of a matrix matching certain conditions? in R

Tags: r, matrix, conditional-statements

I've got this matrix:

```
mm <- matrix(c(1,2,0,0,3,0,0,0,3,4,0,2,2,0,1,0,2,0,0,0,2,0,0,2,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,2,0,3),10,4)
```

and I would like to eliminate all those rows in which only one of the elements is different of 0, for example: `3    0    0    0` or `0    2    0    0`, but I would like to keep those rows with more than one element different of 0, as `3    1    0    0`.

any help on this would be very appreciated.

Tina.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
mm[rowSums(mm != 0) > 1,]
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#[1,]    1    0    2    0
#[2,]    2    2    0    2
#[3,]    0    0    2    1
#[4,]    3    1    0    0
#[5,]    0    2    1    0
#[6,]    4    0    1    3
```